# What is a fast algorithm for finding critical nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm looking for a quick method/algorithm for finding which nodes in a graph is critical.

For example, in this graph:
[image]

Node number 2 and 5 are critical.

My current method is to try removing one non-endpoint node from the graph at a time and then check if the entire network can be reached from all other nodes. This method is obvious not very efficient.

What are a better way?

Comment: See: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1480409. They prove that detecting critical nodes is NP-complete, so I wouldn't expect drastic improvements.

Comment: You are concerned about the nodes, not the links? For example, if I have a link between 3 and 6 then to find critical nodes I need to find links that can be removed, first.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - I remember something about this in an electrical network analysis class but I would need to look it back up, but, depending on the simplifications this can be easy or very hard to solve, as the general case is too difficult, as you pointed out.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - that article proves no such thing, and in fact even the OP's algorithm runs in polynomial time. They prove that the recognition variant is NP-complete, whatever that means. Critical nodes (articulation points, cut vertices) can be found in O(nodes + edges).

Comment: Funny thing the last tab I closed in my browser was http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/3/315.html from a programming competition at Linköping University, wait could monoceres be from Linköping?

Comment: Haha! Funny coincident, yes I am, I labeled it homework so I wouldn't get the answer thrown in my face, but rather get some useful hints :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [biconnected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component). Calling them articulation points instead of critical nodes seems to yield better search results.

In any case, the algorithm consists of a simple [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) where you maintain certain information for each node.

Comment: Thank you very much, articulation points did indeed give better results and I found some very useful links to depth first search.

Answer (score 1):

there are several better ways. [research is always helpful](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=find+critical+nodes+in+graphs&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=fecbcea05c97c6f3)

but since this is homework, the point of the exercise is likely to be to figure it out yourself

hint: how could you decorate the graph to tell you what nodes depend on what other nodes, and would this information perhaps be useful to spot the critical nodes?